# Matlab to read in fix-width text file

Tags: matlab, fixed-width, textscan

I have a text file like below:

```
TestData                                                                     

  6.84 11.31 17.51 22.62 26.91 31.98 36.47 35.85 28.47 20.57 10.50  6.37  test1
  0.24  2.62  4.94  7.17 10.39 15.37 18.73 18.29 12.26  6.46  1.15 -0.33  test2
 68.47 95.04156.07218.39304.31320.22311.69269.22203.01135.60 68.18 55.09  test3

 68.47 95.04156.07218.39304.31320.22311.69269.22203.01135.60 68.18 55.09  test4
...
```

As you can see, the first two lines are comments to ignore. In the following lines, there is a comment at the end of each line too. Each number is in the form of %6f. Also, there are blank lines in between.

I want to read in all the numbers into a matrix to make plots. I tried to use textscan, but had problems to ignore the last column, the blank lines and read in numbers that are connected (e.g., some numbers in the line: test4).

Here is the code I have by now:

```
data=dir('*.txt');
formatspecific='%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f';
for i=1:length(data);
    TestData1=data(i).name;
    tempData=textscan(TestData1,formatspecific,'HeaderLines',2);
end
```

Anybody can help to make a sample code to improve the textscan part?

Comment: post the code you already have

Comment: Why'd you not specify the last string in your format? That's all you need to do, then just kill off the string in your result.

Comment: Even I put strings in the format, I just got 13 blank [] in the output. Do you know why?

Comment: importdata does not work, and I got "Use TEXTSCAN or FREAD for more complex formats".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `textscan` to read a file, you have to "open" it before calling `textscan` and "close" it after; you should use

- `fopen` to open the input file
- `fclose` to close the input file

`textscan` returns a `cellarray` with the content read from the input file; since you are reading more than one file, you should change the way you manage the cellarray returned by `textscan`, actually, as it is now in your code, the data are overwritten at each iteration.

One possibility could be to store the data in an array of `struct` with, for example, 2 `fields`: the name of the input file and the data.

Another possibility could be to generate a `struct` whos each fields contains the data read from the input file; you can automatically generate the name of the fileds.

Another one possibility could be to store them into a a matrix.

Hereafter, you can find a script in which these three alternative have been implemented.

**Code Updated (following the comment received)**

In order to be able to correctly read data such as `95.04156.07` as `95.04` `156.07`, the format specifier should be modified from `%6f` to `%6.2f`

```
% Get the list of input data
data=dir('input_file*.txt');
% Define the number of data column
n_data_col=12;
% Define the number of heared lines
n_header=2;
% Build the format specifier string
% OLD format specifier
formatspecific=[repmat('%6f',1,n_data_col) '%s']
% NEW format specifier
formatspecific=[repmat('%6.2f',1,n_data_col) '%s']
% Initialize the m_data matrix (if you know in advance the numer of row of
% each input file yoiu can define since the beginning the size of the
% matrix)
m_data=[];
% Loop for input file reading
for i=1:length(data)
   % Get the i-th file name
   file_name=data(i).name
   % Open the i-th input file
   fp=fopen(file_name,'rt')
   % Read the i-th input file
   C=textscan(fp,formatspecific,'headerlines',n_header)
   % Close the input file
   fclose(fp)
   % Assign the read data to the "the_data" array struct
   the_data(i).f_name=file_name
   the_data(i).data=[C{1:end-1}]
   % Assign the data to a struct whos fileds are named after the inout file
   data_struct.(file_name(1:end-4))=[C{1:end-1}]
   % Assign the data to the matric "m_data
   m_data=[m_data;[C{1:end-1}]]
end
```

**Input file**

```
TestData                                                                     

  6.84 11.31 17.51 22.62 26.91 31.98 36.47 35.85 28.47 20.57 10.50  6.37  test1
  0.24  2.62  4.94  7.17 10.39 15.37 18.73 18.29 12.26  6.46  1.15 -0.33  test2
 68.47 95.04156.07218.39304.31320.22311.69269.22203.01135.60 68.18 55.09  test3

 68.47 95.04156.07218.39304.31320.22311.69269.22203.01135.60 68.18 55.09  test4
```

**Output**

```
m_data =

  Columns 1 through 7

    6.8400   11.3100   17.5100   22.6200   26.9100   31.9800   36.4700
    0.2400    2.6200    4.9400    7.1700   10.3900   15.3700   18.7300
   68.4700   95.0400  156.0700  218.3900  304.3100  320.2200  311.6900
   68.4700   95.0400  156.0700  218.3900  304.3100  320.2200  311.6900

  Columns 8 through 12

   35.8500   28.4700   20.5700   10.5000    6.3700
   18.2900   12.2600    6.4600    1.1500   -0.3300
  269.2200  203.0100  135.6000   68.1800   55.0900
  269.2200  203.0100  135.6000   68.1800   55.0900
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is very clear and is very helpful. But textscan ignores the leading spaces, and the matrix C is not correct for the line test4. For example, the 3rd number in test4 is 56.072, but it should be 156.07.

Comment: Sorry for this late answer. **I've updated the code**, now `95.04156.07` is correctly read as `95.04` and `156.07`. From your comment it is not clear if you want to "recognize" the empty lines (e. g. the one between `test3` and `test4`. If so, what do you want to inset in the matrix?

Comment: Thanks. The blank line could be either left 0, just be deleted. The program works fine.

Comment: You're welcome, sorta for the initial bug. Perhaps you might want to accept the answer to close the question.